# Bind Context Menu inside ItemsControl?

Tags: c#, wpf, contextmenu

How can I add a ContextMenu to a ItemsControl, where:

- The ItemsSource of the ItemsControl is in the ViewModel of the UserControl holding the ItemsControl
- The CommandParameter of the Context Menu is the ViewModel binded to the Item in the ItemsControl.

I followed [this approach](http://stevemdev.wordpress.com/2013/02/16/wpf-dynamic-context-menu-revisited/). However, I have a Command that Removes Items from the ObservableCollection binded to my ItemsControl. When this happen an exception is thrown inside the RelayCommand. It seems to me as the ContextMenu is not "hiding", so it tries to evaluate the "CanExecute" for its commands, but as the item has been removed it can not cast the parameter to "T" in the CanExecute method of the RelayCommand Class.

**I would like to know how is the correct way to accomplish what I need.**

---

**My Implementation so far:**

**MainViewModel**

```
public class MainViewModel
{
    public ObservableCollection<MyContextMenuClass> ContextMenuItems{ get;set; }
    public ObservableCollection<MyItemClass> MyItems{ get;set; }

    public void AddItem(MyItemClass item)
    {
        MyItems.Add(item);
    }

    public void AddContextMenuItem(MyContextMenuClass item)
    {
        ContextMenuItems.Add(item);
    }

    public MainViewModel(IList<MyItemClass> myItems, IList<MyContextMenuClass> myContextualMenuItems)
    {
        MyItems.AddRange(myItems);
        ContextMenuItems.AddRange(myContextualMenuItems);
    }

    public MainViewModel()
    {}
}
```

**MyItemClass**

```
public class MyItemClass
{
    public string MyText{get;set;}
}
```

**MyContextMenuClass**

```
public class MyContextMenuClass 
{
    public RecentContextMenuItem()
    {}
    public string Caption{get;set;}

    public RelayCommand<MyItemClass> Command{get;set;}        
}
```

**My UserControl** (DataContext = MainViewModel)

```
<UserControl x:Class="MyNamespace.MyUserControl"
         xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
         xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
         xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006" 
         xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"                         
         mc:Ignorable="d" 
         d:DesignHeight="300" d:DesignWidth="300">
<UserControl.Resources>        
     <Style x:Key="CommandMenuItemStyle" TargetType="{x:Type MenuItem}" BasedOn="{StaticResource {x:Type MenuItem}}">
                    <Setter Property="MenuItem.Header" Value="{Binding Caption}" />
                    <Setter Property="MenuItem.Command" Value="{Binding Command}" />
                    <Setter Property="MenuItem.CommandParameter" Value="{Binding PlacementTarget.DataContext, 
                        RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType={x:Type ContextMenu}}}" />                        
                </Style>

                <ContextMenu x:Key="ItemContextMenu" ItemsSource="{Binding ContextMenuItems}" 
                 ItemContainerStyle="{StaticResource CommandMenuItemStyle}"
                 DataContext="{Binding DataContext, RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType={x:Type UserControl}}}"/>

</UserControl.Resources>
<Grid>
    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <RowDefinition Height="Auto"></RowDefinition>
        <RowDefinition Height="*"></RowDefinition>            
    </Grid.RowDefinitions>

    <TextBlock Grid.Row="0" Text="{Binding Title}" Margin="20,5,0,5" Foreground="#FF5D5858" FontFamily="Courier" FontSize="15" Grid.ColumnSpan="2" FontWeight="SemiBold"></TextBlock>

    <ScrollViewer VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Auto" Grid.Row="2" Padding="5,0,0,0">
        <ItemsControl x:Name="myItems" ItemsSource="{Binding MyItems}" >
            <ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
                <DataTemplate>
                    <TextBlock Text="{Binding MyText}" /> <!--Simplied this for the example-->                  
                </DataTemplate>                    
            </ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
            <ItemsControl.ItemContainerStyle>
                <Style TargetType="{x:Type ContentPresenter}">
                    <EventSetter Event="ContextMenu.ContextMenuOpening" Handler="Item_ContextMenuOpening"></EventSetter>
                </Style>
            </ItemsControl.ItemContainerStyle>
        </ItemsControl>
    </ScrollViewer>
</Grid>
```

**My UserControl Codebehind**

```
public partial class MyUserControl : UserControl
{
    /// <summary>
    /// Initializes a new instance of the <see cref="RecentView"/> class.
    /// </summary>
    public MyUserControl()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    private void Item_ContextMenuOpening(object sender, ContextMenuEventArgs e)
    {
        var contentPresenter = sender as ContentPresenter;
        if (contentPresenter != null)
        {
            this.Dispatcher.BeginInvoke(new Action<ContentPresenter>(ShowItemContextMenu), new object[] { contentPresenter });
        }
    }

    private void ShowItemContextMenu(ContentPresenter sourceContentPresenter)
    {
        if (sourceContentPresenter != null)
        {
            var ctxMenu = (ContextMenu)this.FindResource("ItemContextMenu");
            ctxMenu.DataContext = this.DataContext;

            if (ctxMenu.Items.Count == 0)
            {
                sourceContentPresenter.ContextMenu = null;
            }
            else
            {
                ctxMenu.PlacementTarget = sourceContentPresenter;
                ctxMenu.IsOpen = true;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

**The RemoveItemCommand I add to the MainViewModel**

```
new RelayCommand<MyItemClass>(RemoveItem, (param) => true);

    private void RemoveItem(MyItemClassitemToRemove)
    {
        MyItems.Remove(itemToRemove);
    }
```

**The CanExecute method of the RelayCommand**

```
public bool CanExecute(object parameter)
{
    if (_canExecute == null)
    {
        return true;
    }

    if (parameter == null)
    {
        return _canExecute.Invoke(default(T));
    }

    T value;

    try
    {
        value = (T)parameter;                
    }
    catch(Exception exception)
    {
        Trace.TraceError(exception.ToString());
        return _canExecute.Invoke(default(T));
    }

    return _canExecute.Invoke(value);
}
```

I get the error in the **value = (T)parameter;** line, because the parameter is *Disconnected* and can't cast it to **T**.

The **Exception** I get:

> MyProgram.vshost.exe Error: 0 : System.InvalidCastException: Unable to cast object of type 'MS.Internal.NamedObject' to type 'MyItemClass'.
>      at MyNamespace.RelayCommand`1.CanExecute(Object parameter) in c:\MyPath\RelayCommand.cs:line xxx

If I inspect the **parameter** it is a NamedObject:

> - parameter   {DisconnectedItem}  object {MS.Internal.NamedObject}
> - Non-Public members
>         _name   "{DisconnectedItem}"    string

The problem is not the Exception, is the fact that it reaches this point with a DisconnectedItem. This get evaluated multiple times. It is like the ContextMenu remains "forever" in the Visual Tree.

Answer (score 10):

Firstly, just check your parameter values for `null`:

```
return parameter == null ? false : _canExecuteMethod((T)parameter);
```

Secondly, this is the old `ContextMenu.DataContext` problem: The `ContextMenu` is displayed in a different visual tree to the rest of the UI. It therefore has no access to a `DataContext` from the main UI visual tree. Because of this, we have to use a little trick to pass it through to the other visual tree. Our connection between the two is the [`ContextMenu.PlacementTarget` property](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.contextmenu.placementtarget%28v=vs.110%29.aspx).

From the linked page, this property

> Gets or sets the UIElement relative to which the ContextMenu is positioned when it opens.

We can use the `Tag` property of the `ContextMenu.PlacementTarget` object to pass the `DataContext`. Basically, just set the `Tag` property on the object that you will set the `ContextMenu` on. Try something like this:

```
<ItemsControl x:Name="myItems" ItemsSource="{Binding MyItems}">
    <ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <TextBlock Text="{Binding MyText}" Tag="{Binding DataContext, 
                RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType={x:Type UserControl}}}" 
                ContextMenu="{StaticResource ItemContextMenu}" />
        </DataTemplate>                    
    </ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
</ItemsControl>
```

...

```
<ContextMenu x:Key="ItemContextMenu" ItemsSource="{Binding ContextMenuItems}" 
    ItemContainerStyle="{StaticResource CommandMenuItemStyle}"
    DataContext="{Binding PlacementTarget.Tag, RelativeSource={RelativeSource Self}}"/>
```

That's it. Now the UI elements declared in the `ContextMenu` will have access to whatever object you data bind to the `Tag` property. There's absolutely no need for `EventSetter`s to use a `ContextMenu`... it's quite simple *if* you know how.

Comment: Sheridan, thanks for your answer. The parameter is not null, I added more detail to that section of my question so you can see the actual exception. I also implemented your changes, I have a StackPanel surrounding all the controls in my DataTemplate, so I put there the Tag you suggested. The ContextMenu gets added, but I still get the exception. There is an improvement however, since it happens only once per Command in the ContextMenu (I have 5 commands, so I get 5 exceptions each time I remove an item) and then it stops, not like in my implementation that I kept getting exceptions.

Comment: Beautiful use of Tag to propagate the UserControl level data context into the alternate tree for ContextMenus. I had used your technique twice since I had to bind the MenuItem's Visibility property to the UserControl's data context but I still needed access to the local DataContext that is defined within the ListBox.ItemTemplate so I can pull out the particular item I wanted to operate on from MenuItem.Click. So I put a Tag on an Image element in my DataTemplate and then passed that Tag into the ContextMenu's Tag and then bound the Visibility property to the ContextMenu's Tag. Worked great!

Answer (score -1):

It is a known bug in wpf and framework 4.0 try using 4.5 framework.
https://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/feedback/details/619658/wpf-virtualized-control-disconnecteditem-reference-when-datacontext-switch