# How to pass ItemsControl element to RelayCommand bound to a ContextMenu item

Tags: c#, wpf

I have a WPF ItemsControl where I want to be able to delete items via a context menu but I can't get the information which item the user right-clicked on to the relevant handler in the view model (meaning the object I set as the DataContext of my view)

So here is my ItemsControl:

```
<ItemsControl Grid.Row="1"
                ItemsSource="{Binding CurrentComponents, Converter={StaticResource EcComponentsToTrackComponents}, ConverterParameter=Video}"
                dd:DragDrop.IsDragSource="True"
                ItemTemplate="{StaticResource EcComponentPanelTemplate}"
                ItemContainerStyle="{StaticResource EcComponentPanelStyle}">
    <ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
        <ItemsPanelTemplate>
            <controls:TrackPanel MaxTime="{Binding MaxTime}"
                                    MinTime="{Binding MinTime}" />
        </ItemsPanelTemplate>
    </ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
    <ItemsControl.ContextMenu>
        <ContextMenu>
            <MenuItem Header="Delete"
                        Command="{Binding DeleteComponentCM}"
                        CommandParameter="{Binding }">
            </MenuItem>
        </ContextMenu>
    </ItemsControl.ContextMenu>
</ItemsControl>
```

Now to the ViewModel
The ItemSource binds sucessfully to:

```
public IEnumerable<EcComponent> CurrentComponents => _currentProgram?.EcComponents;
```

The Binding to the DeleteComponentCM RelayCommand already works

```
public RelayCommand<object> DeleteComponentCM { get; private set; }
...
DeleteComponentCM = new RelayCommand<object>(deleteComponentCM, () => !IsRunning);
...
private void deleteComponentCM(object component)
{
    if (component is EcComponent ecEomponent)
    {
        _currentProgram.EcComponents.Remove(ecEomponent);
        RaisePropertyChanged(nameof(CurrentComponents));
    }
}
```

So if I put a breakpoint at `if (component is EcComponent ecEomponent)` and click on Delete in the context menu I will stop at this line *but* `component` now is of course the DataContext object itself (so basically `this`) when inside deleteComponentCM.

So my question is: What do I have to change about `CommandParameter="{Binding }"` to pass the item to deleteComponentCM where the user right clicked on to the open the context menu?

While researching this problem I found this:
[Bind Context Menu inside ItemsControl?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21556561/bind-context-menu-inside-itemscontrol)
but I could not get the solution there to work. Also this solution feels very hacky ... in bad way ...
I least in my mind there should be a straight forward solution ... I mean when I have a context menu for items in an ItemsControl isn't it something very normal that I want to know on which item the user clicked on when handling commands from context menu items ???

Comment: Consider setting the ContextMenu on the top level element of the ItemTemplate. Or perhaps in the ItemContainerStyle.

Comment: I already tried to define the context menu in the DataTemplate. While I guess that CommandParameter="{Binding }" will then bind to the item, Command="{Binding DeleteComponentCM} does then not work anymore because DeleteComponentCM is defined in the ViewModel of the hole view (its DataContext) and not in the item class (EcComponent in my case). So I get this error in debug output during runtime: "'DeleteComponentCM' property not found on 'object' ''EcComponent'"

In in this case the question would transform into: What to change about Command="{Binding DeleteComponentCM}" to get it to work?

Comment: You would have to bind the Command to the property of the parent DataContext like `Command="{Binding DataContext.DeleteComponentCM, RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType=ItemsControl}}"`.

Comment: This does not work. After doing it, opening the context menu causes this error in the VS output:
System.Windows.Data Error: 40 : BindingExpression path error: 'DeleteComponentCM' property not found on 'object' ''EcComponent' (HashCode=52840473)'. BindingExpression:Path=DataContext.DeleteComponentCM; DataItem='ContextMenu' (Name=''); target element is 'MenuItem' (Name=''); target property is 'Command' (type 'ICommand')

Comment: Try an ElementName Binding instead of RelativeSource. The idea should be clear, you bind to a property of the DataContext of some parent element, e.g. the ItemsControl, or the MainWindow.